# How can I create a permanent user session in my app?

Tags: mobile, session-cookies, flutterflow

I'm making an app using FlutterFlow. Before the user gets to the main page of the app I need him or her to enter in his or her email address. Basically that's the only info I need for "signup". My question is once a user enters his or email address the first time, how can I create a permanent session for that user?

I'm storing the email in a database but is there a way to create a kind of permanent session once the user has entered an email address? Do I need to create a session on the user in the database? I know normally you would have a user sign up with email and password and after a certain amount of time he or she has to login again. In this instance I don't really need them to login after the first use of the app.

I currently have the login page as the first page in the app. The user enters in the email address and "logs in" to the app. I'm not sure how to bypass this page once the user has entered in an email address.